# Can't import webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, import, pip

I'm trying to log into a site that has a pop up window and I've read that selenium is required for this. I used pip to intall selenium but when I try to import the webdriver I get that the module can't be found. I then right click and try to install but got an error that it can't be installed. When I tried to do it thur the interpretor I got this:

[snipit of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8aWm.png)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you show your import statement?  You should not have to separately run `pip3 install webdriver`, using an import statement like `from selenium import webdriver` after selenium is installed will usually work.

I am also not sure why selenium is required to log in.  Are you automating the log in?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to automate a log in. I have an issue with a forum reading my old autodesk account information. I want to keep my old account so that means I have to use incognito. I'm tierd of having to manually log in every day so I was seeing if I could just place this on my desktop to get it to log in. I was trying to import the webdriver instead of from selenium import. I think this might have fixed it thatnks.

Comment: Okay, if that solved your problem I will make it an answer for you. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to separately install webdriver.  Once you have installed selenium with pip, you can import webdriver by using the import statement:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```